# 3 Row ul with variable screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

from a PHP file that I don't have access to, I receive a bunch of `<li>` elements with a class of "liElHtml". Contained in these are images, so essentially I receive this via AJAX:

```
<li class="liElHtml"><img src="some_img.png" /></li>
```

is there anyway to stack these neatly/evenly in 3 rows without having a static width? The only way I've known how to do this by setting the combined width of the 3 `<li>`'s to the `<ul>`. I've googled around and it seems a static width is the only way I see.

Unfortunately this has to be 3 rows at 100% width to fill the screen because it's for phones.
Right now just to get it to work I set a static width so I have for the html:

```
<ul id="mainScreenUL">
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
#mainScreenUL{
    list-style:none;
    width:150px;
}

#liElHtml{
   display:inline-block;
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
}
```

And the jQuery/javascript

```
$('#mainScreenUL').html(pic_data[1]);
```

The `pic_data[1]` is just one long string of `<li class="liElHtml"><img src="some_img.png" /></li>`

This gives me a somewhat desired effect, is there anyway I can set the width to `width:100%` on `#mainScreenUL` and get the `<li>`'s to stack neatly into only 3 rows?
Thank you for taking the time to read this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if all `li` have the same height you could easily float them and assign a 33.33% width in this way

```
li {
   float: left;
   width: 33.33%;
}
```

then just remember to apply a float clearing to `ul` element

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this now.

Comment: I can't believe how easy that was. Did not think the solution was this simple. Thank you so much. this worked excellent. I can;t accept this answer for another 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
li {
   float: left;
   width: 33.33%;
}
```

Of if you want 100% and can edit the HTML then set the first and last list items to `33%` and the middle one to `34%`.

```
li {
    float: left;
}

.first, ,last {
    width: 33%;
}

.middle {
    width: 34%;
}
```

This changes if you want borders / margins etc but would take out the tiny tiny tiny gap that using `33.33%` leaves.

If you can't touch the HTML then you can always use `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors but you might struggle with some browser support for them.

Comment: do I have to add the .first and .middle to the li elements? or are these selectors?

Comment: These are classes so you would add them to the li elements. You "could" use :first-child, :last-child but if you can edit the HTML easily I'd add the classes.

Comment: Darn, I receive these li's from the php that I have no access to via ajax. They always come in different so I can't even add these classes in with jquery. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: No worries. Look into the pseudo selectors if you have time. They're quite interesting.